# MVC5 Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have looked through the examples on here, but I don't fully understand Views and Partial Views completely in MVC.

I have a view called "Edit.cshtml" with the following code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLine1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLine2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateAbbreviation, "State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.DropDownList("StateAbbreviation", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateAbbreviation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    </div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Since this code will be used on several models, with the same formatting, I would like to create a simple partial view for it. The code in the _AddressPartial.cshtml is exactly what is listed above. In the View, I call it with:

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial")
```

It does not work. I get an HttpCompileException. I assume somehow I need to send my Model object to it, but I am not sure what that Model is? The ViewBag? My question is, what do I need to pass to it?

Comment: Edit your question to include the full text of the `HttpComplieException`.

Answer (score 2):

First declare a model type for your partial view

```
@model MyNamespace.MyModel
```

Since you're reusing this view with different models assign the view a base type or interface.

```
public interface IMyModel
{
    string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The model declaration is then

```
@model MyNamespace.IMyModel
```

So now you can use different models with a reusable view

```
public class FooModel : IMyModel
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    // IMyModel properties
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And usage

```
@model MyNamespace.FooModel

@Html.Partial("_AddressParital", Model)
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", new FooModel { ... })
```

Comment: Does your main view declare a model?

Comment: Yes, it does. I got your solution working, but would the interface be a new class, or can I declare it in the PartialView itself?

Comment: It will be easier to use and find if you define the interface in its own file. If you define its namespace properly you shouldn't have trouble referencing it in the partial view or when you implement a concrete model.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the model through after the partial view's name.

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", model)
```

This will pass the model for the current page, you may want to pass just some of it depending on your model, e.g.

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", model.Address)
```

Note: In your partial view you will need to define the type of the model...

```
@model MyNamespace.AddressModel
```

Comment: When I do this, I get this error: "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context"

I have @model Example.ClassName at the top of the View Page

Comment: Try 'Model' rather than 'model', I may have gotten the case wrong.